# How to check a flv or mp4 in a webpage when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Use JS,I can check a flash object in a webpage when mouse over it, but how to check a flv or mp4 object when mouse over or out ?

check flash:if(event.target.tagName == "EMBED"),but check flv or mp4 , which tagName I can use ? Thank you very much!

Comment: how have you added flv or mp4 files to your page, if you know the elments you can check by there extension like jQuery(element[attr$=.mp4]);

Answer (score 0):

There is a extension on chrome called [**Flashplus**](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/emaamodndfmmmcjepfigalbjjjemadom), which does the exact same thing. You can check the code base for that [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/flashchrome/)